# What is the logic of reverse indexed slices in Python?

Tags: python

Reverse indexing in python with the `x[::-1]` format is very handy, but what is the logic of reversed indexing on *slices*?  I understand that the idea is `[high:low:-stride]`, but I find the following example confusing.  In particular, why is it not possible to slice so that the entire iterable is reversed (without using the implicit `[high::-1]` format)?

This Python 3.6 snippet:

```
s = 'abcde'
for i in reversed(range(0,6)):
    print(i, f'{s[6:(i - 1):-1]:>6}', f'{s[:i]:6}')
```

Returns:

```
5        abcde
4      e abcd
3     ed abc
2    edc ab
1   edcb a
0
```

Concretely, why isn't the 0 line `edcba`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happened?

All magic in [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ebc5ce42a8a9e047e790aefbf9a94811569b2b6/Objects/sliceobject.c), function PySlice_AdjustIndices:

```
if (*start < 0) {
    *start += length;
    if (*start < 0) {
        *start = (step < 0) ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
else if (*start >= length) {
    *start = (step < 0) ? length - 1 : length;
}

if (*stop < 0) {
    *stop += length;
    if (*stop < 0) {
        *stop = (step < 0) ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
else if (*stop >= length) {
    *stop = (step < 0) ? length - 1 : length;
}

if (step < 0) {
    if (*stop < *start) {
        return (*start - *stop - 1) / (-step) + 1;
    }
}
else {
    if (*start < *stop) {
        return (*stop - *start - 1) / step + 1;
    }
}
```

In your case,

```
start = 6, stop = -1, step = -1, length = 5
```

After calculated,

```
start = 4, stop = 4, step = -1
```

Sum up:

```
5         = s[4:4:-1]
4      e  = s[4:3:-1]
3     ed  = s[4:2:-1]
2    edc  = s[4:1:-1]
1   edcb  = s[4:0:-1]
0         = s[4:4:-1]
```

### How to solve?

```
s = 'abcde'
length = len(s)
for i in reversed(range(length + 1)):
     print(i, f'{s[-1:i-length-1:-1]:>6}', f'{s[:i]:6}')
```

output:

```
5        abcde 
4      e abcd  
3     ed abc   
2    edc ab    
1   edcb a     
0  edcba
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Your snippet works perfectly well, although I think that substituting "-1" for "length" as the slice start makes more sense to me: print(i, i-length-1, f'{s[-1:i-length-1:-1]:>6}', f'{s[:i]:6}')

Answer (score 1):

If i is 0, then `s[6:(i - 1):-1]` becomes `s[6:(-1):-1]`, since there are only 5 characters, you take all chars from the 6th place to the last place. And because there are no chars between those two you get an empty string.

If i is 0, then `s[:i]` becomes `s[0:0]`, since there are no charachters between 0 and 0, you get an empty string.

To print 'abcde' backwards, you use `s[::-1]`